# Vue 3, Firebase authentication/authorization different user levels (? security)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3, vue-router

does anyone have any good reference/source/guides to learn how to create different levels of user authorization to lead them to different pages of a web app? (I'm using Vue 3, Vuex, Vite,  Firebase v9),
add-on/side question: any good practice to ensure different user authorizations can't view different vue pages? (like directly viewing certain pages by typing the address) Planning to host the web app on Firebase as well.

Thank you for reading.